# Saving custom view as default

Tags: google-analytics

In my GA account, I have several properties, each with a view.

Currently I'm only interested in

```
Property #19 -> View -> Behaviour -> Events -> TopEvents -> ScrollDepth
```

Clicking my way through all the menus with each visit at GA is quite time-taking if one has to do that often.

Is there a way to save this "window" as a default or as a favorite so that I can access it quicker?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

1. Bookmark the URL when you are in the scroll depth report. Use that bookmark to jump directly to that report.
2. Navigate to your report and then click on `Save` (top right hand corner). You can now access this report via the `Customization > Saved Reports` menu.